# How set button highlighted state when pressed till I press another one?

Tags: android, button, onclick, highlight

Hi I have UI Requirement like this-

There are the four buttons: `Popular`, `A-z`, `NearBy`, `Category`

Any one of them can be pressed at a time. Suppose if `Popular` button is pressed, then the rest of the buttons will seem like not pressed.

Now I want it to stay like this until I press one of the remaining three buttons.
Once any one of the three is pressed that particular button should be highlighted and rest of the buttons should be normal.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html

Comment: since I have reputaion<10 I am not able put image. but i think link i can put http://i.stack.imgur.com/I7b5T.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you should use Radio Buttons and you need to have a selector to define different drawables for different states. Here is how you can have selector. name it as **button_selector** and put it to the drawable folder. And you need to have two different drawables for your buttons as **normal** and **pressed** states. Name it as **button** and **button_selected**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_selected"></item>

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_selected"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button"></item>
</selector>
```

As for the Radio Button ;

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radio_group_card_selector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_group_highlights"
        android:layout_width="69dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/Highlights"
        android:textColor="#21596c"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" >
    </RadioButton>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_group_products"
        android:layout_width="69dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/All"
        android:textColor="#21596c"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" >
    </RadioButton>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_group_mycards"
        android:layout_width="69dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:button="@null"
        android:checked="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/My_Cards"
        android:textColor="#21596c"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" >
    </RadioButton>
</RadioGroup>
```

**So in that way you don't need to deal with the code at RunTime.**

**EDIT :** If you want to use only colors instead of drawables, then you can use the code below for better understanding how it works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"> <!-- pressed -->
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#058CF5"
            android:centerColor="#0273ED"
            android:centerY="0.75"
            android:endColor="#015DE6"
            android:angle="270" />
    </shape>    
</item>

<item android:state_checked="true"> <!-- focused -->
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#058CF5"
            android:centerColor="#0273ED"
            android:centerY="0.75"
            android:endColor="#015DE6"
            android:angle="270" />
    </shape>    
</item>

<item>      <!-- default -->
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#E6E6E6" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: for <item android:drawable="@drawable/button"></item> I am getting error.Do I have to create xml with Name button in drawable folder.Can Inherit the default button of the android

Comment: also in @drawable/button_selected . button_selected is image rite..?

Comment: button is just the name of the image. you can rename it and put it your drawble folder (mdpi, ldpi, hdpi). Then change the name of the button in the selector xml file.

Comment: It worked only thing I want to know is that insted of image can i just set colour for button. I do not want image I just want the colour change

Answer (score 0):

```
private TextView[] viewsArray;
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
      super.onCreate(bundle);
      setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
      TextView[] array // all your buttons
      for (TextView view : array) {
        view.setOnClickListener(mListener);
      }

     viewsArray = array;
}
private OnClickListener mListener = new OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View view){
                    resetViews();
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected);
    }
};
private void resetViews(){
 for(TextView view : viewsArray){
         view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.notselected);
  }
}
```